# Angular conditionally render different element

Tags: angular, render, angular-pipe

I need to do something like depending on the Type property of an object, render a different component:
My pipe returns a specific element
Can I assign to a template variable an expression?

Simplest way to do this?

Thanks in advance

```
  <ng-template let-data="contentArray | pipeFilter:val" >


            <div [ngSwitch]="data?.Type">
              <input *ngSwitchCase="'TextBox'"  />

              <span *ngSwitchDefault ></span>
            </div>

    </ng-template>
```

Comment: I have more than 8 types of components to conditionally render, i wrote just an example

Answer (score 0):

Try using the interpolation {{}} to evaluate the expression.